# Simple Docker Compose Bundling for Testing

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker composition that that I want to test on another computer. (I'm developing in Windows and want to run on a true Linux host.) I just want to do some informal testing and I don't want to go to the trouble to set up a special registry.

Is there a simple way to bundle my composition so I can simply copy and run on the other host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the compose file to recreate the containers on another computer, which should be the best option, or you can use `docker export` to export the image and transfer that image to another system.

Export option does not export the contents of the volumes. More info regarding `docker export` [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export).

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up using `save` / `load` to bring over the actual base images but it's basically the same thing.